Inequality-like symbol to express little-o relation
Recall the definition of little-o notation: One writes $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as $x\to+\infty$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. Intuitively, this means that the growth of $f$ is negligible compared to the growth of $g$.
I would like to know if there is any inequality-like symbol to express this relation that is common in the literature. I am asking this because if there is such a sign, says e.g. $<<$, then whenever we have a chain of little-o relations:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=o(g(x)) \\ 
g(x)&=o(h(x)) \\ 
h(x)&=o(k(x))
\end{align}
we may conveniently express it simply in one line as
\begin{align}
f(x)<<g(x)<<h(x)<<k(x)
\end{align}
I am aware that $\ll$ is used for big-O relation instead: $f(x)\ll g(x)$ as $x\to+\infty$ if there is a constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq Cg(x)$ for all large $x$. What about little-o relation? Is there any symbol for it?

The $\ll$ is common in number theory to express big O, while $\lesssim$ is more common in harmonic analysis to express big O.
In harmonic analysis, sometimes $\ll$ is used to express something akin to little o, and sometimes $\lll$ may even be seen for the purpose of expressing something like little o.
There’s no universal infix notation for little o I’m aware of.
